# How do I apply the differential to points in $\Bbb{R}^2$?

Tags: derivatives

I know how to compute the differential, for example, for $f(x,y)=(x^2,y^2)$, we obtain:

$$f'=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 2 x & 0 \\
 0 & 2 y \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Now I want to apply it to points in $\Bbb{R}^2$. What do I do? First choose values for $x,y$ and then apply to points in $\Bbb{R}^2$? Just looking at the books I have it's not too clear how to do it.

Comment: It might be helpful to think about it as something like a directional derivative. Choosing the point $x=1, y=2$ and applying $f'$ to the vector $[1,0]$ and will give you the derivative of the function $f$ at the point $(1,2)$ along the vector $[1,0]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't exactly understand the question, because I think you have already applied it. Take for example the Gateaux derivative. (In direction $v=(v_{1},v_{2})$)

$\displaystyle \lim_{h \to 0}\dfrac{f(x+hv_{1},y+hv_{2})-f(x,y)}{h}$.

In your example it is $(2xv_{1},2yv_{2})^{T}$ which is $\begin{bmatrix}
 2x&0  \\
 0& 2y \\
\end{bmatrix}$$\begin{bmatrix}
v_{1} \\v_{2}
\end{bmatrix}$.

But I think you have already done that!